# Is my BitLocker-encrypted drive safe from password changing tools, like 4WinKey?

Tags: windows, bitlocker

I've encrypted my PC's C: drive using BitLocker and I would like to know how safe my data is assuming no one gets hold of my password.

I know there are tools that if the person has physical access to my PC can change the passwords of users in Windows or create a new Admin user and so on, for example 4WinKey. If this tool is used, can they then see all the files on the drive?

Comment: If I have physical access I can simply stick a wifi keylogger inside your keyboard. Then you return and type the password, which get sent to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All these hacking tools need to change stuff on the disk for a successful
attack.

As the disk is encrypted, it can't be read. BitLocker encryption has
never been hacked, so your data is safe.
Any attempt to physically write to the disk could potentially damage
the BitLocker encryption and destroy the disk.

You need to be aware that the BitLocker encryption is very safe
against hacks, but it is very fragile and vulnerable, in that a
disk problem could potentially make the data unusable.
When using BitLocker encryption,
you should keep very frequent and good backups of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Attacks without decrypting the disk are possible, but are complicated. In general, the attacker would modify the disk to create a compromise, and then wait for you to boot and login to your computer, making the encrypted data accessible. They then use the compromise to access your data.

In particular, Microsoft removed the "Elephant Diffuser" from Bitlocker for performance reasons; by the analysis of Microsoft's own Bitlocker team, the diffuser was required to prevent certain attacks.  ([Paper](http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2012/readings/bitlocker.pdf) from one of the Microsoft developers, see section 3.2)

In short, without knowing the key, I can flip a single bit in a block (and also corrupt an adjacent block of characters). Across all the software on your computer, if I can guess where the software is stored on disk, it's almost certain I can create a security hole by doing this. Microsoft protects the bootup code from this attack, but not the whole computer. Given that your computer comes with lots of code that you use in addition to boot-up code --- likely installed in exactly the same location on every identical-model computer from that manufacturer --- the "guessing where it is stored" is probably easy.

Most Bitlocker users shouldn't worry about this. There are easier ways to exploit physical access: For example, add hardware to record keystrokes and wait for you to type your password.

It is very difficult to secure a computer against an attacker with unsupervised physical access to the hardware.

Reference.